# IntelliJ Static Web Project to Tomcat or Angular CORs

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat, intellij-idea, cors

I have a static web angular project in IntelliJ IDEA. The static page gets deployed to `http://localhost:63342/Calculator/app/index.html`. I have run into a problem where I try to post some data to a server to get a response back but when I try to post I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <url>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Here is my post angular code:

```
WebIdServer.prototype.getId = function(id) {
    var _this = this;
    var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://<url>,
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'Bearer QWE234J234JNSDFMNNKWENSN2M3',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        data: {
            id:id
        }
    };
    _this.$log.debug(request);
    return _this.$http(request)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            _this.$log.debug("Successfull request.");
            /*called for result & error because 200 status*/
            _this.uid = data.id;
            _this.$log.debug(_this.uid);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            _this.$log.debug("Something went wrong with the request.");
            _this.$log.debug(data);
            /*handle non 200 statuses*/
        });
};
```

I know for a fact that post works because I tried it on a local url of my application that I had running on a different port.

So my question is, since I can't post from localhost I was wondering if maybe deploying this to a tomcat server would fix things. If so, how do you deploy this static web project to a tomcat server? If that's not necessary, then how do I get around this problem I'm having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things regarding CORS. It's a web browser telling you you cannot make a particular call. This is only a front end problem, a script running on a server can call any api regardless of the location. Three different options:

**without config; same hosts**

Without any configuration on your server, your front end's AJAX requests need to match both the domain and the port of the service you're calling. In your case, your angular app at `http://localhost:63342` should be calling a service also hosted on `http://localhost:63342` and then you're sweet. No CORS issues.

**with server side config; different hosts**

If the API is hosted elsewhere, you'll have to configure the API host. Most servers will let you configure access controls, to allow a particular domain to bypass the CORS block. If you have access to the server you're trying to call, see if you can set it up. The [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) website has examples for most servers. Usually this is pretty simple.

**Create a proxy**

This is your Tomcat idea. CORS is only a problem if your front end calls another service. A server script can call anything it likes. So, you could use Tomcat (or Apache, or NGINX, or NodeJS...) to host a script that'll pass on the request. Essentially, all it needs to do is add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the response of the API.

I have never used Tomcat myself, but here's a [blog post](https://chriscarey.com/2014/06/13/apache-proxy-with-cors-headers/) that might have some useful info on how to do that. Combine it with the info on [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) and you should be able to route anything to anywhere.

This process is common. Just look at the popularity of a node package like [CORS anywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere), which is what your tomcat does.

As a disclaimer, how good of an idea this is depends on how you can pass along the credentials and tokens. You don't really want to create a service that'll just blindly call someone else's API with your credentials.

Comment: I dont have any access to the api that I'm calling whatsoever so changing any of its settings is out of the question. But I have a start spring boot java application that I deploy to a tomcat server which calls this same api and it works even though it's also on localhost. Only thing is it uses spring's `postForObject` call. Why does it work there but not in my angular app?

Comment: Isn't the spring call done server side? Servers can call anything. CORS is your *browser* telling you you can't do the request.

Comment: Oh i see. Huh. So the way that all web apps get around this problem is by proxying their request to a tomcat script that calls the api? Assuming they have no control over the said api like me.

Comment: For api's outside your control, probably. There are some other tricks like JSONP that bypass this but I don't come across that very often. I generally proxy them. But, most of my back ends are also written by me and I can just allow the URLs ;) edit; doesn't have to be tomcat, any suitable server script will work.